# Applying Boost UBLAS blas-1 to Matrices

Tags: c++, boost, blas, ublas

How do I apply level 1 blas on a boost::numeric::ublas matrix?
For example I want to compute the maximum entry or the sum of all entries.
Using norm_1 or norm_inf on a matrix gives no compiler error but returns (as it seems to me) arbitrary results.
I am using boost 1.42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`norm_inf` on a matrix computes the matrix norm [*induced*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm) by the infinity-norm on the underlying vector space.  This happens to be the maximum absolute row sum of the matrix.

If you look at **hannes**'s example, the last row of the matrix (i=99, j=0...99) contains:

```
9900, 9901, 9902, ... , 9999
```

If you sum those entries, you get `994950`, which is exactly what `norm_inf` produces.

Comment: That's good to know. Is that documented somewhere? I didn't find it.
Do you know how to calculate the maximum of all the entries? Using your post it could be done with a reshape but that seems a bit weird.

Comment: @Andreas: assuming that the matrix is laid out contiguously in memory (likely, but I don't know if uBLAS guarantees that or not -- someone else will have to weigh in on that point), one could presumably construct a vector object backed by the same storage and call `norm_inf` on that.  Ugly, but I imagine it would work.

Comment: And no, I couldn't find any actual documentation of that, but it makes sense and matches the behavior.  A cursory search didn't find much documentation of uBLAS at all, actually.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example looks like this:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    int main(){
            int l = 100;
            matrix<double> m(l,l);
            for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < l; ++j) {
                            m(i,j)=i*l+j;
                    }
            }
            std::cout << norm_inf(m)<<std::endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

It should give 99, but yields 994950.

This is a one-liner that at least solves the given task:

```
    float infnorm = accumulate(m.data().begin(),m.data().end(),0,std::max<double>);
```

Comment: I don't believe that the one-liner actually works; questioner wants the maximum *absolute* entry.